# jQuery.val() method failing to set value on a select list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code failed when I upgraded to 1.4.1, and worked ok when I rolled back to 1.3.2.

```
var ddlCountry = $("#<%= this.ddlCountry.ClientID %>");
  if (ddlCountry.val() == "") {
    ddlCountry.val(address.country);
    ddlCountry.change();
  }
```

BTW the problem is that the value of the `<select>` list is never set.

Yes, this is all wrapped up in a `$(document).ready` :)

EDIT: For reference this is the code I used:

```
            ddlCountry.find("option").each(function() {
                if ($(this).text() == address.country) {
                    ddlCountry.val($(this).val());
                }
            });
```

Comment: It's a string value which comes from the Google AJAX Search API Geolocation feature.

Comment: What 'value' of the select are you trying to set? The selected item?

Comment: I'm trying to match the item that has the same text as address.country and select it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are setting the **value**, this will work, in jQuery 1.4 is must be the value not text, example:

```
<select id="ddlCountry">
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="2">B</option>
</select>
```

In jQuery 1.3 this works:  `$("#ddlCountry").val("A")`
In 1.4 it doesn't it must be: `$("#ddlCountry").val("1")`

Alternatively if you can't change your dropdown, you can search for and select based on text like this:

```
ddlCountry.filter(function() { 
  return $(this).text() == address.country; 
})[0].selected = true;
```

For reference, [here's the jQuery change that happened](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/f298cce100c6fe23840ac95e66aaea9cb2bfb447).  From the 1.4 notes:

> .val(“…”) on an option or a checkbox is no longer ambiguous (it will always select by value now, not by text value). (Commit)

Comment: It was actually the prior commit that changed the behavior on `<select>` controls: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/261b7efb5f86a5c9a3de8434f3cad858101e4249